# Django + uwsgi + nginx broken pipe

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm doing a stress test with JMeter and with 200 users in concurrency I'm getting this error in the `uwsgi.log`:

```
Wed Oct 24 09:40:50 2018 - uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 306] during GET
```

And this error in the nginx error log:

```
connect() to unix:/var/run/app.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, server: domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/var/run/bbrainers.sock:"
```

How can the server support more than 200 concurrent users?
This must be a wrong configuration I think...

Comment: This indicates that your uwsgi app doesn't manage to scale to 200 users concurrently. You might try using more workers, kill unresponsive workers or fix performance bottlenecks in the python application code.

Comment: We have 3 applications, 2 with uwsgi and 1 with gunicorn, in 3 different servers and it gives exactly the same error with 200 users. I've tried it with a simple hello world and gives the same error.

Comment: Ok. What kind of answer do you want? It does seem like there's a bottleneck. The bottleneck is not nginx, but nginx will not wait forever, so when uwsgi workers take too long to respond, you will get such an error log. Given only the information you have provided, it's not really possible to say anything more specific than that.

Comment: I changed the uwsgi configuration socket from `socket = /run/tmp/app.sock` to `socket = 127.0.0.1:3301` and now the server can support 600 users... I don't know why this happens...